# server misreads beginning of php script file

Tags: php, tags

From time to time, our ISP's *Nix server misreads the beginning of a php scipt ...

```
<?php
ini_set( ... etc
```

... as if it said ...

```
<?phpini_set( " ... etc
```

... that is, as if the 0x0d at the end of the tag weren't there.

Oddly, after a few hours, or a few edits to the file, the misbehaviour goes away.

The usual code editor that generated the file is NotePad++.

What's odd is that our site has dozens of PHP scripts, but when this happens, it affects just one script, usually a session_start.php that does nothing more than call ini_set() a couple of times, set a unique session name, then call session_start().

Our hosting folks haven't figured thus out. Anybody have an idea?